# Tablet orientation

Tags: sensor

Forgive me if this is off-topic.  I haven't been very successful in my search attempts. I keep coming up with how to detect orientation programatically, and that's not what I'm after. What I'm looking for is more of a hardware/electrical engineering question.

How do tablets detect orientation of the tablet?  Some can automatically switch from landscape to portrait when the screen is tilted a certain way, for example.  What hardware is used to detect this, and how does it work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They use an accelerometer, which measures acceleration. Since gravity and  acceleration are indistinguishable, they can also measure gravity.

[image: MEMS accelerometer]

They come in the form of a little chip, like that one. You can get chips with three accelerometers on them, one pointing up, one pointing left, and one pointing forward.  This way, the chip cam tell exactly which orientation it is in, and thus which way up the phone is.

Hack-a-Day also has a good article on [How MEMS accelerometer chips work](http://hackaday.com/2012/05/22/the-engineer-guy-explains-how-mems-accelerometer-chips-work/).
[image: How MEMS accelerometers work.]

This man has his mouth open, which means he is speaking.

But how does the accelerometer work? Amazingly, inside the chip is a mass connected by a tiny spring. Gravity pulls on the mass, moving it around.

[image: MEMS operating principle]

The chip also contains a system for measuring the exact displacement of the mass, and thus the force of gravity in that direction.  This is what the mass and spring actually look like:

[image: MEMS electron micrograph]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed, excellent answer.  I'm not sure if "This man has his mouth open, which means he is speaking." is a jab at my intelligence for asking such a basic question, but I'm laughing too hard at it to be offended if it is.  Thanks for the laugh as well.

Comment: @DavidStratton - Thanks! No offence intended. I just thought it was a funny picture, and deserved a funny comment.

Comment: I was laughing too, otherwise I wouldn't have read the whole answer ;)

Comment: +1 for `This man has his mouth open, which means he is speaking.`

Comment: Gravitation and acceleration are definitely NOT "the same thing"! It's true that both can be measured with the same accelerometer, but it will also give you a reading when accelerating in the absence of a gravitational field, like stevenvh says. -1 until fixed.

Comment: Other possible reasons for an open mouth: yawning, laughing, eating, dentist visit. This is obviously dentist visit!

Comment: @FedericoRusso - What experiment can distinguish between gravity and acceleration ?

Comment: @stevenvh - He looks like a salesman, in which case his open mouth means he's lying ;) Rocketmagnet - Accelerometers are really detecting force. Since gravity is a force (or a property of mass which causes a force), and acceleration is caused by force, an accelerometer cannot distinguish between gravitational force and an external mechanical force causing acceleration.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet - acceleration is the second derivative of distance over time, for a static object speed and hence acceleration are zero. If the accelerometer measures anything in that case it's gravitation. You can speed up a object at a non-constant acceleration. If the accelerometer (without rotating it) outputs a varying signal it has to be acceleration. You can't vary gravitation.

Comment: @Mike - that should be: he looks like a salesman, in which case he's lying, whether his mouth is open or not ;-)

Comment: @Rocketmagnet: Find a quiet spot in empty space, say a few million light years from the nearest galaxy. Start your ion thruster: everything the acceleration sensor measures is acceleration, not gravity. (downvote reversed)

Comment: @Rocketmagnet - BTW, it's not because the *accelerometer* can't tell them apart that they're the same. A scale can't distinguish between a kilo lead and a kilo feathers, and yet feathers are not lead. A microcontroller calculating the derivative of a speedometer's reading over time will only give you acceleration, never gravitation.

Comment: @FedericoRusso - You didn't answer the question. You're walking around in a sealed room, and can't look outside. Are you pulled to the floor because of gravity, or because of acceleration. What experiment can you do to determine which it is?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet: you can't. Just like you can't tell in a dark room whether the light is out or that you're blind. It's not because you can't distinguish them that lights out and being blind is the same. stevenvh gives a good example of a measuring tool (the speedometer + differentiator) which can indicate acceleration but not gravity.

Answer (score 10):

They use **accelerometers**. These are a MEMS (Micro Electro Mechanical System) devices which have a movable part on the chip, whose capacity with the fixed part is variable. When the device is accelerated, due to its inertia the movable part will have a small displacement relative to the rest of the chip, which changes the capacity, and that's being measured.

But gravity is acceleration as well, so you will get a different signal if you hold the device vertically versus horizontally.

Answer (score 4):

The sensor used to detect orientation in devices such as tablets is called an [accelerometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerometer#Orientation_sensing).